# Get path of uploaded image from razor view via jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application. I'm implementing custom image gallery and I meet a lot of difficulties. The target browser is IE9 so I can't use HTML5 File API. All my code is inside strongly typed Razor view in `@using Html.BeginForm` and I want to implement functionality for the user to be able to add/remove as many images as he wants before submitting them.

From my research I understood that there's actually no way to preview image in IE9 before actually saving it so I had to get the code for the gallery outside the main form. Now I can upload images to the server but I need to reload the page in order to show the new one, which is exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve - the feel that the image is only previewed and the only save is performed on main form submit.

From my experience I know that such kind of things are achieved using AJAX but I can't figure out how to write my code. This is what I have for now, but I'm not sure I'm walking the right path:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("UploadPicture", "Forms", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
         <span class="document-image-frame">
         <input type="file" name="file" />
         <input type="submit" value="OK" class="blabla" />
         </span>
    }
```

Then I work with this script trying to find a way to get the path of the newly uploaded image without reloading:

```
$(document).on('click', '.blabla', function () {
        if (confirm('Do you want to save the image?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'POST',
                context: this,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(this).closest('span').remove();
                    $("#ajaxBusy").remove();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    })
```

This script is originally made for other purposes. I don't need the confirmation, but think it doesn't hurts for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here: http://anyfindings.blogspot.com/2013/04/upload-file-in-mvc3-via-ajax.html. I hope this can help you :)